# How can I merge two php arrays with complexity less than O(n.m)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array of ~1500 items, and another one of ~8000, I need to merge them by two keys that they both have (the values for those keys must be the same; besides those keys they don't have other overlaping keys; the resulting array must have all the keys from both arrays). Doing that with nested loops is really hard-boiled.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Example code

(I'm grouping the arrays by the keys group and date in the example)

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'group' => 'group1',
        'date' => '01-2015',
        'name' => 'Fulano',
        'address' => '123 Street'
    ),
    array(
        'group' => 'group1',
        'date' => '01-2015',
        'name' => 'Fulano2',
        'address' => '1234 Street'
    );
);

$array2 = array(
    array(
        'group' => 'group1',
        'date' => '01-2015',
        'phone' => '99999999',
        'age' => '35'
    );
);

$resulting_array = array(
    array(
        'group' => 'group1',
        'date' => '01-2015',
        'name' => 'Fulano',
        'address' => '123 Street',
        'phone' => '99999999',
        'age' => '35'
    ),
    array(
        'group' => 'group1',
        'date' => '01-2015',
        'name' => 'Fulano2',
        'address' => '1234 Street',
        'phone' => '99999999',
        'age' => '35'
    );
);
```

Comment: Can you eventually post some sample code of the arrays with keys that are identical and what needs to be the end result? It is difficult to understand what you need from only reading your description

Comment: More than likely this could be complexity O(n+m) by touching each node once and creating a new array, but without sample data it is very hard to know if I am interpreting your question correctly.

Comment: Your really should use those arrays as *associative containers*, so you can do lookups...

Comment: If you correctly index your data this task is clearly O(k) with k = distinct keys, that is k <= n+m